# How to rotate player model to mouse current cursor position c# unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my character point to where my mouse cursor is, however this isn't functioning properly. I've attached my script "test_1" to the character and makes it turn which is amazing, but it needs to face my mouse position. It's currently just randomly rotating as I move my mouse around the character. I tried attaching the script to the main camera hoping it works, but the camera just flips around in a circle constantly, so the script is currently attached to the player. I'm just looking for a way to rotate and point my character to the mouse position while looking at an angle with the main camera(player view). Here is the [video](https://puu.sh/HQnXc/d6e9c1579d.mp4). A good game reference would be Babo Violent 2.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class test_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 vecWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + Vector3.forward * 10f);

        float fAngle = AngleBetweenPoints(transform.position, vecWorldPos);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, fAngle, 0f));
    }

    float AngleBetweenPoints(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
    {
        return Mathf.Atan2(a.y - b.y, a.x - b.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a -90 degrees or a 90 degrees offset, maybe this might be the issue.

Comment: Where should I add this offset?